# BatchNormalization on 2D data in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, grayscale, batch-normalization

I'm really confused about using batch normalization. For example, i have `(256,256)` image , and i train my network with `batch_size = 4`. I need `(4,64,64)` feature map for each batch, so I have following model:

```
Conv1d(1,1,kernel_size = 1 , stride = 2, padding = 0)
BatchNorm1d(x)
Conv1d(1,1,kernel_size = 1, stride = 2,padding = 0)
BatchNorm1(x)
```

For above model, what should be proper number for `x`?

`BatchNorm` is performed, generally, on channel axis. However, desired feature map should have `(4,64,64)` size. Setting `x` to `1` is not make sense. Am I wrong?

Also I have one question. What is the difference between performing `batchNorm` on channel axis and other axis?